# how to send keyboard to the right host when sharing a keyboard among several hosts

Tags: windows-7, windows, autohotkey, synergy, user-interface

I have two hosts (windows-7) running side by side. I use **Mouse without Borders** to use a single mouse/keyboard (using **Synergy** I have the same issue, so all here applies too).

In each host I am running some AHK scripts that provide some keyboard shortcuts. So if my setup is like this:

- Host A - AHK script A - keyboard A
- Host B - AHK script B - keyboard A (via Mouse without borders/synergy)

While typing in:

- Host A: my hotkey (for example CapsLock-S is always handled by the AHK-script-A (obviously)
- Host B: this is the problem...while typing in this host, my CapsLock-S keyword **SOMETIMES** is handled by AHK-script-B (the desired output) and **SOMETIMES** by AHK-script-A.

When typing in Host B only AHK B shortcuts should be triggered, and not a AHK A one (in Host A).

This probably depends on the order on which some programs (ahk etc) were run on each host, or on what application did last have focus or something, but I have no idea.

Does anyone have some clue on how to make this work? Or how to find some determinism on why sometimes it works and sometimes it does not?

Comment: I'm just speculating here but maybe AutoHotkey isn't the tool for the job? It is listed under 'Conflicting Software' in [Synergy's website](http://synergy-project.org/wiki/Conflicting_Software)

Comment: If I may suggest an alternative software, you could try re-creating your AHK scripts in [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), which does just about everything that AutoHotkey can do. I'm not sure if it'll work though, so maybe create a few basic scripts that test keyboard functionality first? If you'd rather stay with AHK, let me get back to you later after some testing.

Comment: It seems like a functional problem with MwB or Synergy. Does this mostly happen only immediately after moving the keyboard from A to B?

Comment: @harrymc I could not trace it to anything specific, I move my mouse all the time between hosts...

Comment: @Vinayak thanks, but my scripts are too complex to port them to autoit (that I think is pretty similar to AHK), as I don't master neither of them.

Comment: As this happens with two different tools, I'm not sure that a third will solve the problem (although it's possible). You could maybe try a key combination that does not involve a state key such as CapsLock, maybe a function key.

Comment: @harrymc what I was hoping for was someone knowing **why** sometimes works and sometimes does not. This could let me overcome it within my ahk scripts (imagine it depends on focus of some the apps etc, I might be able to modify my ahk scripts to put focus where needed...)

Comment: "Why" is hard to say because it depends on your configuration. I suggested a short-duration key to limit the variables in question. All I can suggest are tests. If you are looking for a full explanation up front, it won't be me.

Comment: It cannot be a matter of focus, since two computers are involved, so the focus in one cannot affect the other. Try changing the hotkey - using CapsLock as a key is not recommended.

Comment: just tested changing hotkey to use Control, does not make a difference, 10 min ago it worked, now it triggers always in Host A

Comment: You describe a situation that is basically impossible. A weak advice: Turn off the mouse and keyboard input in the computer that has nothing to do with MWB. If no solution comes up here, you might have more luck on the [MWB community](https://getsatisfaction.com/mouse_without_borders). Are you using the [latest MWB version from October](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)?

Comment: yes, I am using latest MWB version. Good idea about MWB community, I did not know it existed, asked there too, just in case, thanks.

Comment: Well, at least I helped in something, but my advice does not look like it merits posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the programs you mention although I think I understand the setup.  I would probably debug this by seeing if the keystrokes make it to the AHK script or not and which script is intercepting them.

Two easy tools I might start with...

1) Place a tilde in front of the hotkey definition which lets the keystroke pass through.  Replace the code with a simple tooltip to show what's executing.  See which keystrokes pass through and which ones get blocked.  See if adding the tilde on both systems allows the keystrokes through to the system that is not executing otherwise.

2) Open the script windows on A and B and go to the keystroke log for each.  Send the keys that don't appear to be working and see if they are making it to the script of interest (presumably they are not).

The indeterminism you mention is interesting.  In Remote Desktop and VNC where you have system A possibly intercepting keystrokes you're trying to get to System B, or possibly the other way around, the behavior is pretty deterministic, or can be changed in the software settings as to which keys are allowed to pass through to the remote host and which ones are not.

If you encounter something that doesn't work right but is at least deterministic, then there are other ways to work around that if your two boxes can communicate, or check to see where the mouse position is for example and don't execute if it's at the edge or past the edge on one monitor for example.

Comment: thanks, but this does not help a lot. I'll update the question with further info

Comment: So AutoHotkey might not see that you've changed hosts. Could you think of a way where AutoHotkey sees your mouse movement that changes the host by having it track MouseGetPos using a timer. If that is possible you might be able to reload the script on the correct host as that might "reset" it to a good state OR disable the script in the host you left and activate it in the host you move to. That way only one script can/will be active.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to use the #If command and make the hotkeys specific for each host assuming there is someway to distinguish each host by using a one of the built-in variables for the OS https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#os (A_ComputerName or A_UserName)

More about #If here https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: thanks. But not possible, the scripts I run in both hosts actually contain the same hotkeys...